# Combine multiple coordinate systems in one tikz/pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs

I need two or three distinct coordinate systems in "one tikz environment". The systems are very similar (some linear functions, some labels, the same axis scale). A horizontal shift or `minipage` are not sufficient, because I also need to add some cross-connections between these graphs (which it pretty economic). Those "things betweens the graphs" are often just lines (see picture).

Here is some code which at least "looks like" the thing I want to achieve:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,xmin=-0.5,xmax=10.5,ymin=-0.5,ymax=33]
        \addplot+[no marks,domain=0:6,samples=200, thick] {x+2};    
  \end{axis}
    \hspace{8cm}
  \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,xmin=-0.5,xmax=10.5,ymin=-0.5,ymax=33]
        \addplot+[no marks,domain=0:6,samples=200, thick] {x+4};    
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Just for illustration I manually added a horizontal line to highlight different intercepts of the two lines. This is of cause a very simplistic MWE of what I need to create at the end. Thank you very much.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have multiple axes, which can be shifted (don't use `\hspace` here), and you can define coordinates or nodes within them, which you can connect.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,xmin=-0.5,xmax=10.5,ymin=-0.5,ymax=33]
        \addplot+[no marks,domain=0:6,samples=200, thick] {x+2};    
        \coordinate (X1) at (0,2);
  \end{axis}

  \begin{axis}[xshift=8cm,axis lines=middle,xmin=-0.5,xmax=10.5,ymin=-0.5,ymax=33]
        \addplot+[no marks,domain=0:6,samples=200, thick] {x+4}; 
        \coordinate (X2) at (3.5,2); 
  \end{axis}
        \draw[very thick] (X1) -- (X2);  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, that's too obvious, I didn't thought of it.

Comment: @Marco If marmot's answer helps you, you should upvote and accept (by clicking the tick) his answer. Accepting is the best "thank you" on SE.

Comment: Well, I tried. But the time limit (7 min?) hasn't passed for the acceptance and I havn't had enough credits to upvote. I've done both right now :)

Comment: @marmot One more question, I use scaling for the entire picture `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.4]` this scales everything within my axis-environment, but does not adjust the additional lines, that is to say, it results in a vertical shift of `\draw[very thick] (X1) -- (X2); ` How can I circumvent this?

Comment: @Marco Yes, if you do too many of the transformations there will always be a situation in which pgfplots does not catch up with them, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/463789/121799. I am not saying `scale=1.4` is too much. `pgfplots` is being continuously updated, and you are using an older version (but switching to the newer version only does not fix this here). For the moment, you could do `\scalebox{1.4}{\begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture}}`.