# Filling in Area Under Curve Causes Alignment Issues

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween

I am trying to fill in the area under the curve of sin(x)/x. Here is my code:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames,table,x11names}{xcolor}
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows,positioning, calc, decorations.markings, hobby, quotes,angles,decorations.pathreplacing,intersections}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar,colormaps,fillbetween}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document} 

\begin{figure}[ht]

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,line width=1pt]
\begin{axis}[
color= black,
xmin=-1, 
xmax=7.9, 
ymin=-1, 
ymax=2, 
axis equal image, 
axis lines=middle, 
font=\scriptsize,
xtick distance=1,
ytick distance=1,
%xticklabels={}, 
%yticklabels={},
inner axis line style={stealth-stealth},
xlabel = {$x$},
ylabel = {$f(x)$},
ticks=none,
]

\addplot[black, opacity = 0, domain=0:10, name path = 1]{0};

\addplot[Tan, smooth, domain=0.01:7.5, samples = 300, name path=2, thick] {sin(deg(x))/x}; 

%\addplot[Tan, fill opacity=0.25] fill between [of=1 and 2,soft clip={domain=0:3.1415}];

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\caption{Integrating $\sin(x)/x$ from $0 \le x < \infty$.}
\label{1}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I have the code in a larger document, so here is the output:

[image]

When I un-comment out the line to fill in the area, this happens:

[image]

There is a noticeable vertical gap and the image is pushed to the left. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The culprit is `scale=1.5`, which you should pass to the `axis`, and not to the `tikzpicture`. I *guess* you confuse `pgfplots` otherwise, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/463789/121799). If you wish to have a core-level explanation, I am afraid I cannot provide it, but given [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/463789/121799) one of my first guesses was to change the position of `scale`, and it seems to work. Notice also that the pgfplots library `fillbetween` loads `intersections`, but a slightly advanced version, so you should not load `intersections` (again). I also removed `tkz-euclide` and unused libraries (in order to keep the code tidy), but you may resurrect them and the code still works as it should.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames,table,x11names}{xcolor}
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepgfplotslibrary{%polar,colormaps,
fillbetween}
% \usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows,positioning, calc, decorations.markings, hobby, quotes,angles,decorations.pathreplacing}
% \usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}
%\usepackage{xcolor}


\begin{document} 

\begin{figure}[ht]

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt]
\begin{axis}[scale=1.5,
color= black,
xmin=-1, 
xmax=7.9, 
ymin=-1, 
ymax=2, 
axis equal image, 
axis lines=middle, 
font=\scriptsize,
xtick distance=1,
ytick distance=1,
%xticklabels={}, 
%yticklabels={},
inner axis line style={stealth-stealth},
xlabel = {$x$},
ylabel = {$f(x)$},
ticks=none,
]
\addplot[black, opacity = 0, domain=0:10, name path = 1]{0};

\addplot[Tan, smooth, domain=0.01:7.5, samples = 300, name path=2, thick] {sin(deg(x))/x}; 

\addplot[Tan, fill opacity=0.25] fill between [of=1 and 2,soft clip={domain=0:3.1415}];

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\caption{Integrating $\sin(x)/x$ from $0 \le x < \infty$.}
\label{1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I'm always curious about small issues like this because the solution is not at all obvious.