# Tikzpicture Resizing when Using Axis Environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting, scaling

Here is an example of two generic grids, one made using the `axis` environment in `tikz`, and the other without:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,line width=1pt]

\begin{axis}[
color= black, 
thick,
xmin=-4.9, 
xmax=4.9, 
ymin=-4.9, 
ymax=4.9, 
axis equal image, 
axis lines=middle, 
font=\scriptsize,
xtick distance=1,
ytick distance=1,
inner axis line style={stealth-stealth},
xlabel = {},
ylabel = {},
grid=major,
ticks=none
]

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{figure}

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[black, opacity=0.25] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
\draw[<->,black,thick] (0,-5) -- (0,5);
\draw[<->,black,thick] (-5,0) -- (5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And here is the output:

[image]

As we can see, the grid made using the `axis` environment is smaller than the one made without it. This grid ranged from (-5,5) on both the x and y axis, but if I increase this interval (say to like (-7,7)), the grid using `axis` will not change its overall size, while the grid made without it will. Here is an example:

[image]

My question is, is there a way to scale down the second one so that it will always be the same width, regardless of the axis interval, similar to the first? I know you could manually scale the axis down yourself, but the scaling factor will change depending on the interval of the axis, so that is undesirable.

**EDIT**

Here is something curious that happened to me when playing around with @marmot's answer below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

%First "figure" with graphs 1 and 2 paired up
\begin{figure}[ht]

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt]

\begin{axis}[
scale=1,
color= black!50, 
thick,
xmin=-4.9, 
xmax=4.9, 
ymin=-4.9, 
ymax=4.9, 
axis equal image, 
axis lines=middle, 
font=\scriptsize,
xtick distance=1,
ytick distance=1,
inner axis line style={stealth-stealth},
xlabel = {},
ylabel = {},
grid=major,
ticks=none
]

\node[red,fill=white] at (0,0) {\textsc{Graph 1}}

\end{axis}

\path let \p1=($(current bounding box.east)-(current bounding box.west)$)
in \pgfextra{\xdef\mywidth{\x1}};

\end{tikzpicture} \hspace{1cm}
\ifdefined\myscale
\else
\typeout{Please\space recompile\space your\space file!}
\def\myscale{1}
\fi
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\myscale]

 \clip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
 \draw[black, opacity=0.10] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
 \draw[<->,black!25,-latex] (0,-4.9) -- (0,4.9);
 \draw[<->,black!25,-latex] (-4.9,0) -- (4.9,0);
 \node[red,fill=white] at (0,0) {\textsc{Graph 2}}

\path let \p1=($(current bounding box.east)-(current bounding box.west)$)
in \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\myscale}{\mywidth/\x1}\xdef\myscale{\myscale}};
\makeatletter
\immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\myscale{\myscale}\relax}
\makeatother

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

%Second "figure" with graphs 3 and 4 paired up
\begin{figure}[ht]

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt]

\begin{axis}[scale=0.75,
color= black, 
thick,
xmin=-4.9, 
xmax=4.9, 
ymin=-4.9, 
ymax=4.9, 
axis equal image, 
axis lines=middle, 
font=\scriptsize,
xtick distance=1,
ytick distance=1,
inner axis line style={stealth-stealth},
xlabel = {},
ylabel = {},
grid=major,
ticks=none
]

\node[red,fill=white] at (0,0) {\textsc{Graph 3}};

\end{axis}
\path let \p1=($(current bounding box.east)-(current bounding box.west)$)
in \pgfextra{\xdef\mywidth{\x1}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht]

\centering
\ifdefined\myscale
\else
\typeout{Please\space recompile\space your\space file!}
\def\myscale{1}
\fi

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\myscale]
\draw[black, opacity=0.25] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
\draw[<->,black,thick] (0,-5) -- (0,5);
\draw[<->,black,thick] (-5,0) -- (5,0);

\node[red,fill=white] at (0,0) {\textsc{Graph 4}};

\path let \p1=($(current bounding box.east)-(current bounding box.west)$)
in \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\myscale}{\mywidth/\x1}\xdef\myscale{\myscale}};
\makeatletter
\immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\myscale{\myscale}\relax}
\makeatother

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And here is the output:

[image]

Now, it was to my understanding that if the scale of graph 3 was changed, then the scale of graph 4 would change accordingly. However, that is not the case, graph 2 is actually the one to change!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sets the width of the second `tikzpicture` equal to the one of the first. It uses methods from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116008/121799) and is similar to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/480917/121799). The widths of both `tikzpicture`s are measure and an appropriate scale factor is computed from their ratio. This scale factor is written in the aux file and read in the next run, which is why you need to run the file more than once. Notice that if you know/set the width of the first plot (you can set it with `\pgfplotsset{width=...}`) and `xmin` and `xmax` of the second, you could just compute the scale factor directly. This answer assumes you do not go this route.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,line width=1pt]

\begin{axis}[
color= black, 
thick,
xmin=-4.9, 
xmax=4.9, 
ymin=-4.9, 
ymax=4.9, 
axis equal image, 
axis lines=middle, 
font=\scriptsize,
xtick distance=1,
ytick distance=1,
inner axis line style={stealth-stealth},
xlabel = {},
ylabel = {},
grid=major,
ticks=none
]

\end{axis}
\path let \p1=($(current bounding box.east)-(current bounding box.west)$)
in \pgfextra{\xdef\mywidth{\x1}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{figure}

\centering
\ifdefined\myscale
\else
\typeout{Please\space recompile\space your\space file!}
\def\myscale{1}
\fi
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\myscale]
\draw[black, opacity=0.25] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
\draw[<->,black,thick] (0,-5) -- (0,5);
\draw[<->,black,thick] (-5,0) -- (5,0);
\path let \p1=($(current bounding box.east)-(current bounding box.west)$)
in \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\myscale}{\mywidth/\x1}\xdef\myscale{\myscale}};
\makeatletter
\immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\myscale{\myscale}\relax}
\makeatother
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This happens if I add `scale=0.5` to the options of the `axis` on my machine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt]

\begin{axis}[scale=0.5,
color= black, 
thick,
xmin=-4.9, 
xmax=4.9, 
ymin=-4.9, 
ymax=4.9, 
axis equal image, 
axis lines=middle, 
font=\scriptsize,
xtick distance=1,
ytick distance=1,
inner axis line style={stealth-stealth},
xlabel = {},
ylabel = {},
grid=major,
ticks=none
]

\end{axis}
\path let \p1=($(current bounding box.east)-(current bounding box.west)$)
in \pgfextra{\xdef\mywidth{\x1}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{figure}

\centering
\ifdefined\myscale
\else
\typeout{Please\space recompile\space your\space file!}
\def\myscale{1}
\fi
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\myscale]
\draw[black, opacity=0.25] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
\draw[<->,black,thick] (0,-5) -- (0,5);
\draw[<->,black,thick] (-5,0) -- (5,0);
\path let \p1=($(current bounding box.east)-(current bounding box.west)$)
in \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\myscale}{\mywidth/\x1}\xdef\myscale{\myscale}};
\makeatletter
\immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\myscale{\myscale}\relax}
\makeatother
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another response to your addendum: If you have two graphs, you need to use two independent scale factors. (And there were some `;` missing in `\node[red,fill=white] at (0,0) {\textsc{Graph 1}}` and `\node[red,fill=white] at (0,0) {\textsc{Graph 2}}`.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

%First "figure" with graphs 1 and 2 paired up
\begin{figure}[ht]

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt]

\begin{axis}[
scale=1,
color= black!50, 
thick,
xmin=-4.9, 
xmax=4.9, 
ymin=-4.9, 
ymax=4.9, 
axis equal image, 
axis lines=middle, 
font=\scriptsize,
xtick distance=1,
ytick distance=1,
inner axis line style={stealth-stealth},
xlabel = {},
ylabel = {},
grid=major,
ticks=none
]

\node[red,fill=white] at (0,0) {\textsc{Graph 1}};

\end{axis}

\path let \p1=($(current bounding box.east)-(current bounding box.west)$)
in \pgfextra{\xdef\mywidth{\x1}};

\end{tikzpicture} \hspace{1cm}
\ifdefined\myscaleOne
\else
\typeout{Please\space recompile\space your\space file!}
\def\myscaleOne{1}
\fi
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\myscaleOne]

 \clip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
 \draw[black, opacity=0.10] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
 \draw[<->,black!25,-latex] (0,-4.9) -- (0,4.9);
 \draw[<->,black!25,-latex] (-4.9,0) -- (4.9,0);
 \node[red,fill=white] at (0,0) {\textsc{Graph 2}};

\path let \p1=($(current bounding box.east)-(current bounding box.west)$)
in \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\myscaleOne}{\mywidth/\x1}\xdef\myscaleOne{\myscaleOne}};
\makeatletter
\immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\myscaleOne{\myscaleOne}\relax}
\makeatother

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

%Second "figure" with graphs 3 and 4 paired up
\begin{figure}[ht]

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt]

\begin{axis}[scale=0.75,
color= black, 
thick,
xmin=-4.9, 
xmax=4.9, 
ymin=-4.9, 
ymax=4.9, 
axis equal image, 
axis lines=middle, 
font=\scriptsize,
xtick distance=1,
ytick distance=1,
inner axis line style={stealth-stealth},
xlabel = {},
ylabel = {},
grid=major,
ticks=none
]

\node[red,fill=white] at (0,0) {\textsc{Graph 3}};

\end{axis}
\path let \p1=($(current bounding box.east)-(current bounding box.west)$)
in \pgfextra{\xdef\mywidth{\x1}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht]

\centering
\ifdefined\myscaleTwo
\else
\typeout{Please\space recompile\space your\space file!}
\def\myscaleTwo{1}
\fi

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\myscaleTwo]
\draw[black, opacity=0.25] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
\draw[<->,black,thick] (0,-5) -- (0,5);
\draw[<->,black,thick] (-5,0) -- (5,0);

\node[red,fill=white] at (0,0) {\textsc{Graph 4}};

\path let \p1=($(current bounding box.east)-(current bounding box.west)$)
in
\pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\myscaleTwo}{\mywidth/\x1}\xdef\myscaleTwo{\myscaleTwo}};
\makeatletter
\immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\myscaleTwo{\myscaleTwo}\relax}
\makeatother

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason, the second grid does not scale with the first. So, for example, if I change `scale=1` to `scale=0.5`, only the size of the first grid changes, and not the second. Although this does assure that the two are the same size when `scale=1`, which is honestly good enough for me, but I'm just curious as to why they both don't scale.

Comment: @AidenKenny It does scale if I put the scale information into the axis, e.g. `\begin{axis}[scale=0.5,...`. Notice that one should scale the axis, not the tikzpicture, because otherwise you can confuse `pgfplots`. There have been issues e.g. when filling some curves and scaling the `tikzpicture` instead of the axis.

Comment: it still does not scale for me, even with the `scale=0.5` inside the axis environment.

Comment: @AidenKenny I added the full code to make sure we are talking about the same thing. (And did you compile twice or three times?) (Ironically you had the issue with the scaling in the `tikzpicture` [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/477876/121799)... ;-)

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure, I copied and pasted your code in and only the first grid will scale, regardless of how many times I compile. The only potential issue I could see is that I have `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}` in my preamble, not `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}`; for some reason when I try to use 1.16, I get the error message Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, 'compat=1.16' is unknown in this context. Please use at most 'compat=1.15'."

Comment: @AidenKenny I compiled with `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}` and it still works for me. I see how this can be frustrating for you, but I can only assure you that it does work absolutely fine on my machine. For me it is frustrating as well since I do not see what can go wrong, and, again, it works as it should on my machine.

Comment: I made an edit to the question, I found something that could potentially explain the problem?

Comment: @AidenKenny I made another update. If you have two pictures you want to adjust, you need two independent scale factors. Once this is done, it does work on my machine as it should. (BTW, your code did not compile because of missing semicolons.)

Comment: IT WORKS! Another fantastic job, marmot!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15} 
\xdef\defsize{4}
\xdef\cursize{5}

\newcommand\myscale[1]{\defsize/#1}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\myscale{7}]
\draw[black, opacity=0.25] (-7,-7) grid (7,7);
\draw[<->,black,thick] (0,-7) -- (0,7);
\draw[<->,black,thick] (-7,0) -- (7,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\myscale{3}]
\draw[black, opacity=0.25] (-3,-3) grid (3,3);
\draw[<->,black,thick] (0,-3) -- (0,3);
\draw[<->,black,thick] (-3,0) -- (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: This is just an idea for the examples in your code ... For more complex output that depends on other lengths and not just the known axis widths you should use the maximum widths in there... so, could possibly not work